# What's special about "Deep Breath: Bonus Edition"?

Tags: doctor-who

My TV guide is listing [Deep Breath: Bonus Edition](http://www.locatetv.com/tv/doctor-who/9386999) as airing on Friday at 8 on BBC America. What makes it more special than Deep Breath: Regular Edition?

Comment: Probably some special features, e.g. 'behind the scenes', interviews with the cast, or whatever.

Comment: BBC America usually cuts the episodes to American length with standard commercial inserts after they premiere right?  Might just be referring to an uncut airing.  Can't confirm that though, otherwise I'd post it.

Comment: @Radhil I'm pretty sure they don't do that anymore. I know a lot of people complained.

Comment: The breath... is *deeper*.

Comment: @PaulD.Waite Introducing DARTH VADER as THE DOCTOR

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would venture to say there is nothing different about the episode itself, other than it being part of the special BBC America has been running since August 15th, ['The Doctor's Finest'](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZfePsHJz2k).

Episode blurb from tvguide.com

> Season 8 begins with Peter Capaldi as the 12th Doctor. In the opener, the Doctor and Clara are in Victorian London where a dinosaur is on the loose and a spate of deadly spontaneous combustions take place. Includes bonus content and interviews presented by YouTube personality Hannah Hart.

Most likely, the bonus content will be the fan videos, clips from Comic Con, and sneak peeks at Season 9, that Hannah mentions in the YouTube clip.

Comment: Do you have a source?

Comment: @Rogue Jedi.  Unfortunately, no.  I am making an educated guess, based on watching the previously aired episodes of 'The Doctor's Finest'.

Comment: @AngeloDeMichaels Have those other episodes also been labeled "Bonus Edition"?

Comment: @user24601 I don't remember them being listed by anything other than the episode title.  Even the upcoming episode is only listed as "Deep Breath" by Xfinity's (my cable provider) online and on-tv guides, and by tvguide.com.